# Can I travel after visa's intended travel date?

Tags: visas, uk

I just finished applying for my visa and had originally planned to travel on the 30th of September, so I put that as my intended date of travel. But now I will not be leaving until close to the second week of October.

How does this work, will I still be able to travel with this visa even though it says I intended to arrive on September 30th?

Comment: Where are you applying for a visa to? Is your visa already issued?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will be able to travel in October even though you told them your travel date is in September.

All entry clearances issued by a British consulate have a start and end date and they use your intended travel to assign those dates.  You can request a start date up to 90 days from your application date, or you can request an immediate start date.  They do not hold you to the dates, those questions are not meant to be evidential.

You can travel any time between the start date and end date.  If you need to change the start/end dates you can ask the consulate to do that, but once you arrive in the UK and clear UK immigration control the dates are 'locked in'.